# How to search in a SQL database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, search

I have a table with the following columns:

1. user_id
2. user_name
3. user_unit
4. user_last_name
5. user_first_name
6. user_email

I want to write a query that the user declares a string that contains a word/part of a word/user_name/user_id/full name/ext. and the query returns all rows the contains the string, sorted by most relevant.

Any offers?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a very basic question not well suited to our Q&A format. I'd suggest beginning with a SQL tutorial such as the one provided by w3schools. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp That should help you.

Comment: I probably didn't write the question right. I want 1 string to run on all fields and check it all, but I need it to return to me with the rows ordered by most relevant. i.e. the field that is closest to the right string.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the columns together and use `like`:

```
where (user_id || ' ' || user_name || ' ' || user_unit || ' ' ||
       user_last_name || ' ' user_first_name || ' ' || user_email
      ) like '%' || :input_string || '%'
```

You haven't specified the database, so this uses the standard SQL concat operator.

Comment: Ok, thanks! but how do i sort it according to the most relevant answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
var word = 'user Input';
var query = word+"/user_name/user_id/full name/ext"
```

user `query` variable to query data.

Comment: I probably didn't write the question right. I want 1 string to run on all fields and check it all, but I need it to return to me with the rows ordered by most relevant. i.e. the field that is closest to the right string